# How to define context path of context.xml in web application in Tomcat 6?

Tags: root, tomcat6, context.xml

Can anyone suggest to me where I have to put the context path in a Tomcat server? Do I have to put it in `context.xml` or do I have to create a new .xml inside this `apache-tomcat-6.0.18\conf\Catalina\localhost`?

When I type the URL `http://localhost:9796/` this should redirect me to the login page. But I am getting `404 exception`. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the context root information in Server.xml, for all the web modules(WAR) deployed in a server.

1. If you are deploying the application directly from the tomcat server
       by copying the WAR directly into webapps folder you can add the
       context's information in server.xml.
2. If you are deploying the app in
           Eclipse then you need to create a context.xml in the META-INF folder
           and add the entry like below

> ```
> <Context crossContext="true" docBase="{urModuleName}" path="/{URL}"
> reloadable="true">
> ```